# .net webapi OAuth2

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

I am making an API in .net that is using WebApi.  The API is going to be consumed by an adroid native application.  I would like to implement OAuth2 for authentication however I don't want to use Entity Framework and the baked in implementation when you create a project seems to use that.  Is there an easy way to implement the OAuth2 modules without the Entity Framework integration or do I have to try and write my own classes that implement the same interfaces as the user classes in Entity Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to. That's just there for convenience. First, you need to understand how OAuth works from an Authentication Server perspective. I have a feeling you are using OWIN.

In that case, you need to enable OAuthAuthentication and use their delegates to intercept when clients are calling your API for authentication (so that you can generate a token). Then you just authenticate against a database... worst case scenario you can do.. "SELECT u, p from Users where u = 'user' and p = 'password'.... My point is that you don't need Entity Framework at all. Once you have a valid user, then you create a token, add some claims to it and send it back. Done. There are plenty of examples online.

Comment: Thanks, I will research Owin itself then.  I was researching how to add OAuth2 to WebPI, maybe I was asking for too complete a solution rather than understanding the underlying parts

Comment: OWIN (Katana) comes with a "middleware" for OAuth. Very very simple to use and open source as well. You can find it on Github in case you're interested in the details (but I wouldn't waste my time unless you are doing it for educational purposes).

In asp.net website there is a very good tutorial on OWIN OAuth middleware.

Comment: Although there are lots of tutorials online, none seemed to do exactly what I wanted.  I watched the Microsoft videos about it which gave me a good understanding and then used the RavenDB identity implementation as a base to build my own.